# Using a $ref and other properties within a JSON Schema

Tags: jsonschema, jsonpath, json-schema-validator, jsonpointer, json-ref

In a JSON Schema is is valid to have a `$ref` and then other properties within the same schema, for example.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "title": "My schema",
    "properties": {
        "scripts": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/scriptsBase",
            "description": "More docs.",
            "minLength": 10
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "scriptsBase": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Base Description",
            "minLength": 5
        }
    }
}
```

If this is allowable, then what are the rules when it comes to resolving properties defined in the `$ref`ed and the `$ref`ing schemas (in this example `minLength` and `description`. But potentially this could become much more complex if `allOf` etc where defined in both.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer in [json schema property description and "$ref" usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565090/json-schema-property-description-and-ref-usage), basically if a $ref exists all other properties are ignored.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pbryan-zyp-json-ref-03#section-3

> 3. Syntax
>
> A JSON Reference is a JSON object, which contains a member named
> "$ref", which has a JSON string value.  Example:
>
> { "$ref": "http://example.com/example.json#/foo/bar" }
>
> If a JSON value does not have these characteristics, then it SHOULD
> NOT be interpreted as a JSON Reference.
>
> The "$ref" string value contains a URI [RFC3986], which identifies
> the location of the JSON value being referenced.  It is an error
> condition if the string value does not conform to URI syntax rules.
> **Any members other than "$ref" in a JSON Reference object SHALL be
>
> ignored.**

Comment: You should be aware that this changes with draft 8, which allows keywords alongside `$ref` as a shorthand to putting two schemas inside an `allOf`.